# Multiple img slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

can somebody explane me how to make slideshow like this: http://prntscr.com/84wtzy

In this divs on image are imaages.
So when I click on arrow it shows me second page with 5 images like this one on image.

Can someone please answer?